# Дизайн мобильного приложения

Tags: android, design

Ребята, хочу приукрасить своё приложение, но понятия не имею как это делается.

Гуглил много, но особо ничего нету про дизайн мобильного приложения.

Расскажите, как делается дизайн? Как его сделать?

Вот обычный пример Layout, который мне нужно как-то аккуратненько обрисовать: сделать аккуратный ListView хотябы, фон я умею менять)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hodite.com.shcherbuk.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:text="@string/select_city"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_select_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:divider="#ada1a1"
        android:dividerHeight="2px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот item_list:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

Comment: панель "Выбор города" можно например поменять на `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, для списка использовать, например, `CarouselRecyclerView`

Comment: @Flippy Это View элементы какие-то или что это?Никогда просто не слышал об этом

Comment: Да, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` можно найти в `design support library`. `CarouselRecyclerView` это тоже библиотека с эффектом появления элементов списка с анимацией карусели (как в приложении Мегафон ЛК)

Comment: Но это все как вариант. Всяких украшательств много, советую посетить Android Arsenal

Comment: А вообще есть специальные гайдлайны Material Design если хотите быть "в тренде"

Comment: тоесть стоит почитать про Material Designe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. По цветам: коды цветовой палитры material design вот здесь   [Color-Style-Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette)
2. Пример с RecyclerView,CardView (можно CardView заменить обычными LinearLayout) 
   [Android tutorial:Create RecyclerView, CardView and option menu for RecyclerView item](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgRENEDNuFg)

Answer (score 1):

Во первых что бы делать современный дизайн, неплохо было бы привести приложение к современным элементам UI. Как минимум можно сделать cardView и  RecyclerView вместо лист вью. В том числе и потому, что с кардВью проще работать и проще приводить к современному виду.
+ почитать про материальный дизайн и привести приложение к такому виду, подобрав цветовую палитру, отступы, хакругления прозрачность и прочие элементы.
Так же неплохо было бы добавить цветовые темы в настройках типа день-ночь или другие.
Картинки отрисовывать по возможности в векторе.
ДУмаю этого достаточно что бы любое приложение выглядело более менее стильно.